# Must baal keriah be in same reshut as congregation

Tags: halacha, torah-reading, minyan

Due to corona virus, I've seen some shuls are arranging davening such that everyone is outdoors except the Torah reader who is indoors and a door or window is opened so that the reader can be heard outside.  Rav Herschel Schachter [here](https://youtu.be/ZMT4Wq1OCCc) talks about how one who says any davar sh'b'kedusha must be in the same reshut as the minyan.  So for example one standing in a different room or with a permanent immoveable mechitza cannot lead kaddish.  So how can the baal keriah be inside alone reading the Torah while the entire minyan is outside listening?

Comment: I'm skeptical of your claim. Are you sure they don't have a minyan standing inside too?

Comment: The shul I attend is among them. I know there isn’t a minyan inside.

Comment: Why not ask your shul's rabbi who he is holding like? Clearly it isn't R' Schachter

Comment: Are any of the members of the tzibbur able to see the ba'al kriyah?

Comment: I suggest you read siman 55. There is no precedence for this to work. This is not like a chatzer kitana and gedola as the opening is not paratz bimilua. The Chazzan is not 'pulled after' the tzibur like when on a bima inside the shul, as we have a special leniency for the bima situation. Seeing from behind the beis haknesses is not comparable as there the tzibur is inside and the tenth guy is seen from outside and completes the minyan. Especially according to Aruch HaShulchan who says we only allow one to be seen and complete the minyan, not more.